# Is GCC's implementation of type_traits bad practice?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, metaprogramming

So, I was wondering about some template meta-programming best practices as a fascinated beginner. One of the things I ran into when doing more complex compile time computations was the small recursion depths (which are inefficient because they instantiate the template) that compilers default to, and the toll that even simple calculations can do. For example, writing an integer sequence generator (working like python's `range()`) was extremely limited when using an append style. Namely, I suspect it ran in `O(n^2)` time (due to copying) with high coefficients (hard to tell because that is dependent on the implementation of GCC's parameter pack spreads). Continually recursing gave a linear depth however. Trivially, a divide and conquer method solved this with, giving approximately (by the same obfuscating principles as before) a `O(nlog(n))` effieciency, with the positive side effect of approximately `O(log(n))` depth from the linear `O(n)` depth with the prior.

Now that my basic head space is described, I'll ask about these standard library implementations from GCC source. Though they are helper functions, doesn't that make it all the more important to decrease template instance depth?

```cpp
/// add_const
template<typename _Tp>
struct add_const
{ typedef _Tp const     type; };

/// add_volatile
template<typename _Tp>
struct add_volatile
{ typedef _Tp volatile     type; };

/// add_cv
template<typename _Tp>
struct add_cv
{
    typedef typename
    add_const<typename add_volatile<_Tp>::type>::type     type;
};
```

Couldn't some depth (and visual headache) be avoided by not calling the templates from one another: (and also using type-aliases lol)

```cpp
// add_const
template <typename _Tp>
struct add_const { using type = const _Tp; };

// add_volatile
template <typename _Tp>
struct add_volatile { using type = volatile _Tp; };

// add_cv
template <typename _Tp>
struct add_cv { using type = volatile const _Tp; };
```

Let me know if there's something wrong with the second type, or if the difference isn't really important. Thanks so much!

Comment: It is usually more beneficial to have duplicated code to be in one place (not duplicated) rather than play it easy on the compiler.

Comment: “Visual headache” is in the eye of the beholder. Writing that cv is the combination of c and v also makes sense. As for performance, there is no recursion or anything involved, so that's O(1) either way.

Comment: One advantage of using both existing templates for `add_cv` is it allows a specialization of `add_const` or `add_volatile` to be used without also having to specialize `add_cv`.

Comment: I try not to look at Standard library code too hard and do not recommend using it as an example of good code. The folks writing a mainstream Library implementation have two main concerns: 1) it produces the behaviour described by the Standard and 2) it is efficient as hell. In support of 2, without violating 1, they often do things that are unsavory and can get away with it because they know the compiler the library is shipping with and the broad hardware it's going to run on intimately and can fully embrace implementation defined behaviour and abuse the living hell out of undefined behavioiur

Comment: There are some videos on YouTube from presentations at the major C++ conferences, including discussions on the performance of template metaprogramming.  Look for [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky0JdPh_LgE)

Comment: Rather than good above, I wanted to use idiomatic, but ran out of characters and now the comment looks somewhat snide. A mainstream Standard Library implementation is good code. It does exactly what the implementers set out to do. It does it efficiently. Library implementations just aren't something you should learn from until you know enough to recognize when and where you should use the dirty tricks the library exploits.

Comment: @user4581301 you should also notice that a lot of them have huge amounts of legacy code, which no one would be interested in cleaning up.

Comment: As well as piles of conditional compilation to handle and harvest efficiency improvements and edge cases as soon as you do need the library to port too different hardware. GCC supports such a wide umbrella that it's a huge accomplishment simply not being a gibbering wreck, let alone working as well as it does.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That would be an advantage. If there were such specializations. OR adding them would be legal.

Comment: This is just the old question of how much effort is worth investing in avoiding code duplication. The duplication is very minor, but technically there (you implement adding `const` and `volatile` twice). And it is almost certain that nobody will ever change how those traits work. But nonetheless it is a case of "don't repeat yourself". Different people have different thresholds for where DRY stops being worth while, relative to potential performance loss or loss of readability. But it all comes down to a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Type-aliases using `using T = whatever;` are avoided in libstdc++ because it should still be usable if you compile in [pre-C++11 modes](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Yes, avoiding `std::add_volatile` and `std::add_const` in `std::add_cv` would be marginally easier both on the compiler and the maintainer. Cppreference.com even does it in [their example-implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv).

Someone suggested [in the comments](/questions/67536517/is-gccs-implementation-of-type-traits-bad-practice/67537055#comment119372691_67536517) that delegating to the other two modifiers would allow picking up specializations without specializing that too. This "advantage" is specious though, as there neither are nor will ever be any in the standard library nor is it legal for anyone to add their own.

To wrap it up, sometimes slightly cumbersome code stays just because it is fit for purpose, meaning it doesn't degrade performance of the result, nor burdens the compiler too much, and thus nobody ever bothers revisiting it. Submit a pull-request if you care.